# Creating an array list in one class from objects constructed in another

Tags: java, object, arraylist

**I have 3 classes : -**

> **Tell** - The main program
>   **Item** - The individual telephone directory items
>   **Directory** -  A directory object which stores all the items.

---

What I'm trying to do is create an array list within directory which stores the objects from the item class and this is how I'm doing it.

*From Tell,* I'm invoking method as: -

```
Directory.add(name, telNo);
```

*Directory Class: -*

```
public class Directory
{
    ArrayList<Entry> entries = new ArrayList<Entry>();
    // Add an entry to theDirectory
    public static void add(String name, String telNo)      
    {
         entries.add(new Entry(name, telNo));
    }
}
```

*Entry Class: -*

```
public class Entry
{
    String name;
    String telNo;
    public TelEntry(String aName, String aTelNo )
    {
        setNumber(aTelNo);
        setName(aName);
    }

    private void setNumber(String aTelNo)
    {
        telNo = aTelNo;
    }
    private void setName(String aName)
    {
        name = aName;
    }

}
```

However my program does not compile, and it displays this error: -

```
"non-static variable entries cannot be referenced from a static context"
```

Can anyone explain what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to declare your *ArrayList* in `Directory` class as static since you are using it from a *static context* - your *`add`* method. And also you can make it `private`, as your fields should be private, and provide a `public` accessor method to access it.

```
private static ArrayList<Entry> entries = new ArrayList<Entry>();
```

You can only access static variables from a static context. Because, non-static variables need an instance of your class to be used, and there is no instance available in a static context, so you cannot use them.

Answer (score 2):

Declare `entries` `static`. You can access only static variables inside static context.

```
static ArrayList<Entry> entries = new ArrayList<Entry>();
```